# Adding parameters to password reset key

Tags: password, parameter

I'm trying to add in parameters to the url generated for password reset for a user.

In this case I wanted to add a &lang parameter to determine a users selected language and set a cookie.

How do I update the WP reset password key which is sent in the emails? I'm not sure where to find this?

Thanks